The app “Runner” has been killed by the operating system because it is using too much memory. Xcode 15.3 and iOS 17.4
Problem Description:
My Flutter App crashes randomly after a few minutes or even seconds of debugging with real device. It doesn't seem to be linked to any specific code which causes this error.
The weird thing is that everything worked fine with the app on my old MacBook (MacBook Air 2019, Intel Chip with Xcode 14 and iOS 15). I got a new MacBook (MacBook Air 2024, M4 Chip) and now the same App crashes randomly.
I know it says it crashed because the app uses too much memory but even with the Analytic Tools in Xcode I couldn't find any resources which might caused the crash.
I get the following Error in Xcode:

When I click on Details, this is what I get:
The app “Runner” has been killed by the operating system because it is using too much memory.
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 11
Recovery Suggestion: Use a memory profiling tool to track the process memory usage.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-05-21 17:03:35 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
}
--
The app “Runner” has been killed by the operating system because it is using too much memory.
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 11
Recovery Suggestion: Use a memory profiling tool to track the process memory usage.
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone11,8";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.4.1 (21E236)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.24";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.100.58";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 2;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 89667;
    "operation_errorCode" = 11;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.4.1 (Build 23E224)
Xcode 15.3 (22618) (Build 15E204a)
Timestamp: 2024-05-21T19:03:35+02:00

flutter doctor -v Output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.19.5 on channel stable at /Users/user/Desktop/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 300451adae (8 weeks ago), 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
    • Engine revision e76c956498
    • Dart version 3.3.3
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15E204a
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.88.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Jonas iPhone (2) (mobile) • 00008020-000205890163002E • ios            • iOS 17.4.1 21E236
    • macOS (desktop)           • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta)
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.209

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Question:
Has someone any experience with this kind of behavior or knows a possible solution?

I have experienced this kind of things in production. Sentry also catches these kind of exception. In my case i have lots of images in pageview in which pages are from 200kb to 2mb.so in case user scrolled too fast I received these kind of error

@Ultranmus I also thought of this possibility but in my case it doesn't make any sense because the same app with the same code ran fine on my old MacBook. I don't have that many or high resolution images in my app. It has to do something with how Xcode or the new iOS Version handles Memory.

Xcode getting better with every release...
I also randomly experience this issue with several XPC services when debugging, in different apps. Most likely Xcode is the culprit here...
